# Content-based video searching using python or other alternatives?

Tags: python, video

I came across this library PimPy http://pim.gforge.inria.fr/pimpy/
and it has the content-based retrieval feature http://pim.gforge.inria.fr/pimpy/examples.html#video-content-based-retrieval.

But I've been facing too many errors. I've been googling alot for solutions but haven't found any. So basically I'm wondering if it is possible or not. I've read some posts that mention python is not a preferred platform for video processing.

So I would like to know if there are other libraries that support this? I know that its possible, Videosurf.com have already released an android app

. so it should be possible.

It would be great if someone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is high-level language and not suitalbe for video processing as is. What Python libs do is that they provide a wrapper around some lower lever graphics library to rely the actual processing.

Python: easy programming

Low level library: needed speed for video processing

You should stop googling around Python, but you should instead Google around generic solutions for which you can provide a Python wrapper if you need to integrate them with your service.

Unfortunately I am no expert in content-based video searching so I cannot recommend any solutions for there, but re-asking the question leaving the Python out and having some more tags might bring you more hits.